# rails new column foreign key 'null'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

I've successfully created a new column 'page_title' in a table 'schedule_items'. 'page_title' exists in the 'pages' table. 'page_id' exists in the table 'schedule_items' so I know pulling in a foreign key works, and can see in the schedule_item.rb model, the relationship "belongs_to :page". I can't figure out how to make the column 'page_title' pull in the associated 'page_title' column from 'pages' table. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please post a [mcve], so that we can see what you tried and help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Rails has special code that can understand that when you define `belongs_to :page` that it should look for a column named `page_id`.

Rails has no code for any other kinds of columns. There is no code that will automatically look for `page_title` - if you want that, then you need to do something else.

A common way of dealing with this would be to use a delegation eg:

```
class Schedule
  belongs_to :page
  delegate :title, :to => page
```

Then you could do something like:

```
schedule = Schedule.find(12345)
schedule.title # => "Title for page associated with this schedule"
```

Comment: Hats off to you for making any sort of sense of that question.

Comment: :D sometimes I can figure it out... most times I can't... :)